# py.test deal with both pylint and flake8 when importing features from a module

Tags: python, pytest

So, I have roughly this code:

```
from .fixtures import some_fixture


def test_whatever(some_fixture):
    print(some_fixture)
```

I get two warnings from `flake8` for this:

> F401 '.fixtures.some_fixture' imported but unused

and

> F811 redefinition of unused 'some_fixture' from line 1

I'm not going to move fixtures anywhere, but "decorating" every test definition and every import with `noqa` and `pylint` comments seems like a very sad and colorless life (especially so that sometimes it will silence a legitimate warning, s.a. when a fixture isn't really used).

What else can I do?

Answer (score 17):

The better way is to place your fixtures in the `conftest.py` file which is the recommended location for shared fixtures.

They will be automatically discovered by pytest. You won't have to import them so no F401 and since the arguments won't be colliding with the imports no more F811.

Comment: Using conftest.py is good, but note that if you're importing the fixtures from another file rather than defining them in conftest.py (which might be desirable sometimes) you have to use `__all__` to placate flake8 (similar to common practice in `__init__.py` files)

Answer (score 10):

Use flake8's and pylint's directives to disable checks:

```
from .fixtures import some_fixture  # noqa: F401; pylint: disable=unused-variable

def test_whatever(some_fixture):
    print(some_fixture)
```

There is no way around that.

Comment: The `conftest.py` solution by Abid seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: `conftest.py` is cleaner in the sense that it avoids suppressing the warnings, but also means any file in that directory or deeper inherits the fixture.  That might not be desired.